# Python Flask: Get database rows as dictionary

Tags: python, flask

I'm building an application using Flask MySQLDb and wondering how to return database rows as dictionaries (like PHP's FETCH_ASSOC). The default `fetchall()` method of the cursor class returns a tuple, and there's nothing about returning a dict in the [docs](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) of the underlying library.

So far I've been executing code the following format, but getting a dict with column names as keys would really help:

```
g.cursor.execute('SELECT email, password FROM users WHERE email = %s', [request.form['email']])
        row = g.cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: http://www.gadzmo.com/python/using-pythons-dictcursor-in-mysql-to-return-a-dict-with-keys/

Comment: Check out SQLAlchemy :) http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database

Comment: @Trent I know! SQLAlchemy is the best thing out there, but currently I'm keeping the learning curve shallow because my application is really small.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `cursorclass` argument in the connect method and specify [DictCursor](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor-class.html) when you create the cursor.

See here for [example](http://www.halfcooked.com/mt/archives/000969.html). In a nutshell:

```
import MySQLdb
from MySQLdb.cursors import DictCursor

conn = MySQLdb.connect(cursorclass=DictCursor)
g.cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Comment: My problem here is that my code uses the MySQL class in the flask-mysqldb module, whereas the example uses MySQLdb directly. Is there a difference? Any compatibility issues (I'm on 3.4)? What infuriates me is that I can't, anywhere on the Web, find the source code for this infernal class. :(

Comment: I'm still confused as heck (poor documentation, extreme fragmentation, etc.) but at least this worked as expected. Thanks a lot! It seems like I must directly use `mysqlclient` because this is what `flask-mysqldb` is based on.

Comment: It seems you can set `MYSQL_CURSORCLASS` in flask configuration, see [here](http://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Great, but what possible values can it take?

Comment: Probably the `DictCursor`? Not sure, haven't worked with flask-mysql

Comment: Perhaps. I'll try it the next time I'm making something. But seriously, I hate the library author for that.

Answer (score 12):

Simply add the line

```
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'
```

Comment: Finally what I was looking for.

Comment: Also what i was looking for, makes sense cheers. This should be in the documentation page.

Answer (score 2):

the flask-mysql [github page](https://github.com/cyberdelia/flask-mysql/issues/42) recommends

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from pymysql.cursors import DictCursor

mysql = MySQL()
mysql.init_app(app)
conn = mysql.connect()
cursor = conn.cursor(DictCursor)
```